# Example of a RoboCup 3D Soccer bot?

Tags: physics, simulation, robocup

I'd like to write a bot to play in the 3D [RoboCup](https://web.archive.org/web/20161019223408/http://www.robocup.org:80/about-robocup/) software soccer simulation league that runs under [SimSpark](http://simspark.sourceforge.net/).  Can anyone point me at some code that already deals with communication with the server, etc?

[image]
<sub>(source: [sourceforge.net](http://simspark.sourceforge.net/wiki/images/thumb/a/a3/SoccerSimulation_TwoTeams.png/800px-SoccerSimulation_TwoTeams.png))</sub>

Ideally this would be .NET code, but an example produced in any language would still be useful.

**EDIT** For anyone who is not familiar with the RoboCup 3D Soccer league, check out [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hitSyiQ9iqg&feature=autofb).  It has some pretty funny moments, if you're into that sort of thing...

***EDIT 2*** Still no answers?  I put together a page on Wikipedia dedicated to the [RoboCup 3D Simulated Soccer League](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RoboCup_3D_Soccer_Simulation_League) for further information.

Here's another [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3rnomVdXx9I) of the SEU-RedSun team kicking goals at the 2008 RoboCup championship.  Their agents are considerably more sophisticated (and coordinated) than those in the first video I linked to.

Comment: wow, 4 brand new tags. Are none of the 36,000+ existing tags useful for you?

Comment: @skaffman - you're welcome to suggest some.  I don't quite know how to read your comment.  What's your point?

Comment: Are you trying to create a bot to game the system? if so you won't get much help here.

Comment: @scunliffe -- RoboCup is a software soccer league.  You can *only* create a bot if you want to participate :)

Comment: Thanks @Drew - I was a bit trigger happy with my comment - I didn't realize (until I Googled) that this was a live robot competition thing. Looks really cool, but I'd have to guess that you'd need a whole pile of robotic skills to pull this off too? e.g. not just code.

Comment: @scunliffe -- actually the img you added to the question is misleading.  RoboCup has many leagues, some of which use hardware.  I'm interested in the pure software league which simulates robots.  See the video I posted for an example.